# How should I get and set a folder's group and user permission settings via Core Service?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I can get strings representing group and user permissions for a given folder with the following.

### Code

```csh
// assumes Core Service client "client"

var folderData = client.Read("tcm:5-26-2", new ReadOptions()) as FolderData;   
var accessControlEntryDataArray =
  folderData.AccessControlList.AccessControlEntries;

Console.WriteLine(folderData.Title);

foreach (var accessControlEntryData in accessControlEntryDataArray)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1}",
                    accessControlEntryData.Trustee.Title,
                    accessControlEntryData.AllowedPermissions.ToString());
  }
```

### Output

> Some Folder
>   Everyone has **Read**
>   Editor has **None**
>   Chief Editor has **None**
>   Publication Manager has **None**
>   Interaction Manager has **None**
>   T2011-CB-R2\areyes has **All**
>   [scope] Editor 020 Create has **Read, Write**
>   T2011-CB-R2\local1 has **Read, Write, Delete**
>   [rights] Author - Content has **None**

Seems like the four possible values for `AllowedPermissions are:

- `None`
- `Read`
- `Read, Write`
- `Read, Write, Delete`
- `All`

This works great for my use case to create a folder permissions report. I can `.Replace()` these to a familiar notation (e.g. `rw--` or `rwdl`).

**But is manipulating these `string` values the right approach to *set* permissions as well? I'd imagine I'd want objects or maybe enums instead.** Could someone point me in the right direction?

Also I noticed I get some, but not *all* non-applicable groups set as `None`. I don't specifically need them here, but I'm curious at what determines whether those get returned--did I miss something in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rights` and `Permissions` are enums, indeed. You can set using the method below. If you want to set multiple rights you should do something like "`Rights.Read | Rights.Write`"

Keep in mind that this method will return you object that you have to save \ update \ create after

```csh
    public static OrganizationalItemData SetPermissionsOnOrganizationalItem(
               OrganizationalItemData organizationalItem, 
               TrusteeData trustee, 
               Permissions allowedPermissions, 
               Permissions deniedPermissions = Permissions.None)
    {
        if (organizationalItem.AccessControlList == null)
        {
            organizationalItem.AccessControlList 
                    = new AccessControlListData
                    {AccessControlEntries = new AccessControlEntryData[0]};
        }
        var entries = organizationalItem.AccessControlList
                                        .AccessControlEntries.ToList();

        // First check if this trustee already has some permissions
        var entry = entries.SingleOrDefault(
                               ace => ace.Trustee.IdRef == trustee.Id);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            // Remove this entry
            entries.Remove(entry);
        }

        entries.Add(new AccessControlEntryData
        {
            AllowedPermissions = allowedPermissions,
            DeniedPermissions = deniedPermissions,
            Trustee = new LinkToTrusteeData { IdRef = trustee.Id }
        });
        organizationalItem.AccessControlList.AccessControlEntries 
                                                      = entries.ToArray();

        return organizationalItem;
    }
```

Comment: +1 and accepted, much cleaner than what I had. Thanks for the useful method as well.